# Split String Into Small Parts [JAVA]

Tags: java, regex, arrays, string, split

I have a string that says Bingo and I want to break it to smaller parts and make each of them a String array, for example;

`String s = "BINGO"`

I want it so to be like this;

```
String s[] = new String[s.length];
s[0] = B;
s[1] = I;
s[2] = N;
s[3] = G;
s[4] = O;
```

I tried this but it failed;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    String sentence = "BINGO";
    String words[] = sentence.split("a-zA-Z");

   for (String word : words) {
    System.out.println(word);
}
```

It just prints out "BINGO" whereas I want to split them, now what regex should I use ?

Comment: What is `smaller parts`? One character?

Answer (score 1):

use `sentence.split("");`

1. split method gets a regex by what should split. It means that everything catched by regexp won't be in result.
2. If you want regexp to catch letters you should place the `a-zA-Z` in square braces (`[a-zA-Z]`) read regexp documentation.
3. use empty string if you want to get every character in result. If you don't need whitespaces, use `\\s*` (whitespace characters 0 or more times)

**EDIT:**

place `(?!^)` before `\\s*`. `^` is the start of the string and `(?!^)` negates that.
So `(?!^)\\s*` means NOT startpoint of the string and whitespaces 0 or more tames.

Comment: I use the (\\s*) and now it treats the first string array as blank space. What should I do to make it treat the first string array as "B" instead of blank space ?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to convert to array of chars

```
char[] letters = word.toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`String.getChars()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getChars%28int,%20int,%20char%5B%5D,%20int%29).

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just new into programming so by just linking me to a method, doesn't really helps me. What should I do, from there ? s.getChars(???) ???

Comment: @e-zardYusof Like this: http://ideone.com/jRf8YE . But then it's a character array, not a string array.

Answer (score 0):

```
String sentence = "BINGO";
String words[] = sentence.split(""); // empty regex

for (String word : words) 
        System.out.println(word);
```